# pictures on website taking a while to load

Tags: javascript

I've literally just wrote the same post a couple of minutes ago. The whole thing was so lazy and poorly written I'm re posting the question. Apologies for the first post.

Here is my website:

top-drawer.net/artists.html

When I use a browser that isn't my own it's very noticeable how long the pictures take to load in. I'm talking about the artists page and the individual artist own pages. When you click on the pages you watch the images slowly load in and when you are showing someone new the website it really doesn't look professional at all.

What is causing this and how do I go about fixing it??

just for information I'm using google chrome to view my work.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: can i take this down that is awful apologies to everyone for that is terrible from me didn't mean to waste anyone time

Comment: Add the option fadeFirstImage: false to the backstretch script. See my post for a better explanation

Answer (score 1):

It takes a little long because there is a script which change the opacity of the img element from zero to 100%, that is why you cannot see them immediately.
Try to change it from:

```
$('#slider').backstretch([
  "/../images/bennyPalmer/2.jpg"
  , "/../images/bennyPalmer/8.jpg"
  , "/../images/bennyPalmer/3.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

to:

```
$('#slider').backstretch([
  "/../images/bennyPalmer/2.jpg"
  , "/../images/bennyPalmer/8.jpg"
  , "/../images/bennyPalmer/3.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750, fadeFirstImage: false});
```

Note that you need the last version of the repository. Here the reference:
https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/pull/345

Answer (score 1):

Your images take so long to load (in the Artists page) because they are big files. Try creating thumbnails of the large images

Comment: They are not really big images, 300k for a jpeg is more than acceptable.

Comment: First 2 I looked at were over 1MB - sure, that's not big, unless you're stuck in Australia with crappy ADSL :p